# SQL beginer query that split string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column :
That contains a lot of world like this : beetween ";"

I want to be able to locate where is ";"

```
1; 2; 3;
```

Example :

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`col1`, ';',+1)
```

I'll get the first one but i am not able to get only the 2nd or the 3rd
if i do +2 
i'll get : 1 2  and i want only 1 or 2

Comment: Do you want some kind of loop or what?

Comment: Yes , its a kind of loop but in only one query example :
I just want to get in Nikaia; Xanthi; Stravroupoli; Kozani; Agrinion
the 5th word only not the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [substring_index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#substring_index):

```
select  substring_index(substring_index(col1, ';', 3), ';', -1)
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e20f19/4/0)

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. You can use `substring_index` to return all to the left or right after a number of occurances, answer updated